# Use row index number as string in new column rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column to my `DataFrame` in which each row includes a string with the row index + 1. This is what I have attempted:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'some_column': 'foo'}, {'some_column': 'bar'}])
>>> df['new_column'] = f'some string {df.index + 1}'
```

But is just gives:

```
>>> df['new_column']
0    some string RangeIndex(start=1, stop=3, step=1)
1    some string RangeIndex(start=1, stop=3, step=1)
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.assign(new_column='some string '+(df.index+1).astype(str))
  some_column     new_column
0         foo  some string 1
1         bar  some string 2
```

or

```
df['new_column']='some string ' + (df.index+1).astype(str)
```

**Alternative**

```
(df.rename_axis('new_column')
   .reset_index()
   .assign(new_column=lambda x: 'some string '+ 
                                x['new_column'].add(1)
                                               .astype(str))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm curious as to why `df['new_column'] = f'some string {(df.index + 1).astype(str)}'` and `df['new_column'] = 'some string {}'.format((df.index + 1).astype(str))` do not work. It only seems to work using the `+` sting concatenation operator...

Comment: You are welcome,  I think you can't pass an index object to the format function